# How to generate a link to a html page with parameters WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to create a ResetPassword Page and I need to create something like that!

`myApi.azure.com/ResetPassword?hash=YYYYYYYYYYYYYY`

I already know how to create a link to another controller, but that way it would trigger the Action just with the click, and what I need is pass the hash as parameter inside of that URL and them, call a controller!

```
var link = new Uri(Url.Link("ValidationEmailUser", new { Code = emailToken }));
```

Comment: Do you need a redirect? From controller? Or from view?

Comment: From the controller, when I check if the e-mail exist, the user will receive a link to the reset page with a hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult RedirectAction()
{
    var urlFormat = string.Format("https://www3.olx.com.br/account/forgotten_password/?hash={0}", emailToken);
    var location = new Uri(urlFormat);
    return this.Redirect(location);
}
```

Comment: Yeah but, that way it wouldn't redirect to my ResetPage but to the controller, that's the thing, I don't know how to do it. Look the OLX URL when someone trying to reset the password..

`https://www3.olx.com.br/account/forgotten_password/?hash=0000000000000000000000000` Thats What I need to do, create a link with a hashcode as parameter!

Comment: I thought you had the right link. I have updated my answer.